# Display message after drag and drop (not pop out message, simply html)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a display in html after dropping an item, but not in pop out message. I've tried .confirm and .alert, but they're pop out message. I've also found .html method, but my items ended up gone missing and their text changed to the output message. 
I know I need to add a function inside the droppable item (where the stuff will be dropped), but not sure what will work.

I found these code online because I'm using it as an interface function but I'm trying to modify it for my use.

```
$('.listdragable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // get target list name
        var newList = $(this).parent().attr("id");  
        $(this).append($(ui.helper.children()).clone().draggable({
            //make dropped items in new list draggable
            helper: function() {
                var selected = $('#' + newList + ' input:checked').parents('li');
                if (selected.length === 0) {
                    selected = $(this);
                }   
                var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
                container.append(selected.clone());
                oldselected = selected;
                return container;
        }               
        }));        
        //remove dropped items from old list
        oldselected.remove();       
    } 
});
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: explained what you don't want...but forgot to explain what you do want. Some html would help also